# Difference between span tag and a div tag

Tags: html

I had a doubt in my mind that what are the differences between these :-

```
<div> TEXT </div> 
<span> TEXT </span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple words `div` is a block element and `span` is inline element.

> Generally, block-level elements may contain inline elements and other block-level elements. Inherent in this structural distinction is the idea that block elements create "larger" structures than inline elements.

and inline element

```
Generally, inline elements may contain only data and other inline elements.
```

[Block Level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements) & [Inline Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Inline_elements)

Comment: <div style="display: inline" /> ;)

Comment: @Spook — Which causes a block element to be rendered as an inline element, but doesn't affect any of the other rules that apply to block elements (which aren't all that consistently applied, which is why the term has (AFAIK) been dropped in the HTML 5 draft).

Comment: I've learned, that most of non-control HTML tags (control, ie. `a`, `img`, `table` etc.) can be easily converted to another using CSS styles, so I use to say *what the tag should be used for* rather than *what the tag is* and that's the reason of my comment. Nevertheless, it's good to know about block and inline elements, I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 2):

`<div>` is a block element and `<span>` is a inline element.

These links help you to understand the inline and block elements.

http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/

http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/

http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/qt/block_vs_inline_elements.htm

Answer (score 1):

DIV is typically for a block element where as span is an in line element.

So you typically do something like

```
<p>This word is <span class="blue">blue</span></p>
```

You should probably not do

```
<span class="blue">
    <div class ="layout">
        <p>Content</p>
        <img src = "this.jpg" />
    </div>
</span>
```

Now, there is the CSS attribute called `display` which will allow you to display a div in line (`display:inline;`) which can cause further confusion since visually it may let you display the same render with either tag. Whether the code is 'correct' or not may or may not mean you get desired results in your browser! Typically, the results probably are what you want  but the issue may occur when the site becomes bigger and you then realise something is not right and have to fix it at a later stage!

Any way, W3Schools define it as

> The  tag is used to group inline-elements in a document.
>   The  tag provides no visual change by itself.
>   The  tag provides a way to add a hook to a part of a text or a part of a document.
>   [Source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp)

And

> The  tag defines a division or a section in an HTML document.
>   The  tag is used to group block-elements to format them with CSS.
>   [Source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp)

Comment: "You would not do" - *Could* not do, span elements may not contain p elements.

Comment: @Quentin, yes, sorry, I never write "will/won't" type answers, I had meant `should`